# CRM 2011 Ribbon is missing from Marketing List

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

The `Ribbon` is missing (Not displayed) only from system Entity `Marketing  List`, everywhere else (on all other entities) its ok. We have no javascript related to this Entity. We have nothing Custom in `RibbonDiffXml` below is RibbonDiffXml xml:

```xml
<RibbonDiffXml>
  <CustomActions />
  <Templates>
    <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates"></RibbonTemplates>
  </Templates>
  <CommandDefinitions />
  <RuleDefinitions>
    <TabDisplayRules />
    <DisplayRules />
    <EnableRules />
  </RuleDefinitions>
  <LocLabels />
</RibbonDiffXml>
```

Can someone help me, how to bring it back?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know which version of CRM are you using, but if you are in online or applied UR12 in on-premisse, there is some issues with UR12, check this [fix](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/02/13/customized-case-ribbon-missing-ur-12/).

Comment: I have seen it already, this link says:
"Luckily, this only applies to the `case entity` where the ribbon has been customized". I need to do it for `Marketing List`, on Marketing List i can't find `Enable Form Assistant`.

Comment: I can't test because is all fine with me. Have you upgrade recently i found another [link](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/10/15/resetting-crm-2011-ribbon/), take a look.